# Fail to add a new word to the "good" list of vim spell checker

Tags: linux, vim, spell-check, vimrc

I am using the vim spell checker. 
When I do "zg" (Add word to "good" list) it apparently works. 
If I save and quit ( with :wq command) and re-open the document all words get reddish indicating that they are wrong, except those which were manually added.
For example, if I have ten words and seven of then are already ok, then I add the other three words to my "ok list" with zg command, if I close and re-open this file all the seven words will be marked as incorrect and only those three will be marked as "good words".

I can see that two new files are created when I do zg for the first time:
~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.add
~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.add.spl

And it's like vim only sees the above-mentioned files and not the original one, wich is:
~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.spl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.add` and `~/.vim/spell/pt.utf-8.add.spl` are the only files shown in my `~/.vim/spell` directory.

Two things I would try first:

1. Rename the `pt.utf-8.spl` file. Vim's [official documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#spellfile) indicates that these word list files should have the following generic form: ".{encoding}.add"
2. Try setting `spellfile` explicitly using the specifications described in the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#spellfile).

---